# For email messages, where is the colon-less From field specified?

Tags: email

If one opens an mbox file with an editor, every message seems to start with a *From* followed by one space and then an address and date.  Is this part of the mbox syntax or part of the email format specification [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)?  According to the [Wikipedia article on the mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox), there is no mbox RFC.  Isn't the colon-less *From* related to UUCP?

I'm having to parse some mboxes and I wanted to know how to handle the colon-less *From*.

Comment: Check if there is e.g. a Perl library for this task. The possible lines are very varied, and going into MIME is a whole new world of hurt.

Comment: `Mail::MboxParser` is what prompted the question.  I remember `sendmail` adding the colon-less _From_ and MboxParser needs it, but I'm not sure it is part of any spec.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280525/117549

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging into the mbox format.  The short answer appears to be that, while there is no RFC specifying the mbox format, already in the mid 1970s the From+space was being used to separate different mail messages strung together in one text file.

There is a mail command in the 1st Edition of Unix from Bell Labs (November 1971), but the source code has been lost, so I'm not sure how it worked.  The mbox makes its appearance in [the 3rd edition](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man1/mail.1).  The the source code for [the 5th Edition of Unix (from June 1974)](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s2/mail.c) has been recovered and one can see that the `From`+␣ marker is already used to separate messages.   The syntax then is From, space, a name with no spaces, and a ctime string (the 24 character human readable timestamp).

The `From`+␣ line was introduced by the sending process, which prepended it to the message typed by the sender before appending it to the mailbox of the recipient.  This practice was followed by succeeding mail delivery programs, including the once popular [sendmail](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/sendmail/prf1_02.htm) that originated with the Berkeley variants of Unix.

The early versions of the Berkeley Unix were additions to the Bell Labs version.   The second Berkeley Software Distribution of March of 1979 already has an elaborate mail program were we can see the beginnings of the file structure that will later form sendmail.  The code in [`head.c`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2BSD/src/Mail/head.c) identifies the `From`+␣ marker and introduces a few modifications: that the name has to be 17 characters or less (which did not survive into the sendmail era) and that there can be further text between the end of the date and the newline (which did).

Successors of sendmail, such as [qmail](http://www.qmail.org/qmail-manual-html/man5/mbox.html), have formalized the syntax of the of the mbox, including handling lines in the mail message that begin with `From`+␣, an issue that has led to [a diversity of mbox formats](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000383.shtml).