# What is the unix mailbox format?

Tags: email, standard, file-format

`man git-format-patch` makes reference of the *UNIX mailbox format* which is a term I am unfamiliar with.

A google search for "*UNIX mailbox format*" and similar expressions lists many hits with the term *mbox* in it.

There is even a man page [(man mbox)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/mbox.5.html) for mbox.

I am lead to conclude that *mbox* and the *UNIX mailbox format* are the same thing, but I am not 100% sure.

Can someone confirm (or deny) my assumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone confirm (or deny) my assumption?

Yes, Both are same.

**`UNIX mbox format`** is used by AsyncOS when messages are archived (in anti-spam and anti-virus configuration) and logged (in the message filter log() action).

**`mbox`** is traditional UNIX mailbox format. Users' INBOX mboxes are commonly stored in `/var/spool/mail` or `/var/mail` directory. Single file contains multiple messages and is the most common format for storing email messages on a hard drive. All the messages for each mailbox are stored as a single, long, text file in a string of concatenated e-mail messages, starting with the “From” header of the message.

Comment: IMHO "the most common format" has been true.  Multiple (small) messages in single file have made sense to preserve precious disk space. In era of bigger messages and cheaper disk space it is mostly "unwillingness to change" that keeps "one mail one file" (maildir) away.

Answer (score 3):

The two are not equated in an RFC or other standard, but if you read further, you will notice that searching for the two terms together finds several articles which equate them, as well as pointing out a commonly used *different* format, `maildir`.

[RFC 4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155) (written in September 2005, which is *recent*) says

> The mbox database format is not documented in an authoritative
> specification, but instead exists as a well-known output format that
> is anecdotally documented, or which is only authoritatively
> documented for a specific platform or tool.

Further reading:

- [About *mbox*](https://serverfault.com/tags/mbox/info) (points to [RFC 4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155), which gives the details)
- [11.2 What are the advantages of the various mailbox formats Pine supports?](https://www.washington.edu/pine/faq/sysadmins.html)
- [mb2md: convert mailbox to Maildir](http://www.gerg.ca/hacks/mb2md/)
- [Mailbox formats supported by Dovecot](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/dovecot-1.1.7/doc/wiki/MailboxFormat.txt)

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX, the original `mail` and the Berkeley `mail` (in Sys-C UNIX the Berkeley MUA [mail user agent] was called `mailx`) stored messages in `/var/spool/mail/username`, and if you saved messages they were moved to your `/home/username/MAIL` file.

All the messages were in a single file separated by a blank line and starting with a single `From - date_string` line, called the `mbox` format.  Note that each message also should also contain a `From:` line that is part of the standard RFC email format.

There were a couple of alternatives to `mail`, namely `mh`, `elm` and `mutt`.  These used a directory hierarchy called `maildir` format, essentially using the filesystem as a database.

When Netscape Communicator came out, and later broke up into Firefox and Thunderbird, it retained the `mbox` format from UNIX and Linux, but maintained a different file for each "account" or source of email.  Note that to retain the speed of using the filesystem style `maildir` format (yes it was faster for lots of emails), Netscape invented an index file ending in `*.msf`.

- More information on the `mbox` format can be found at this [LoC site](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000383.shtml)
- More information on the `maildir` format can be found e.g. [here](http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html)